# Setting up Windows XP with bootcamp - Why does OSX Boot and Skip XP Installation?

Tags: macos, windows-xp, bootcamp

#### [Asked and Answered on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/40028/setting-up-windows-xp-with-bootcamp-why-does-osx-boot-and-skip-xp-installation)

I am attempting to install Windows XP on my Macbook.  I use bootcamp assistant and partion 32GB for windows.  I insert the XP disk and I go through the initial blue screen disk formatting screens.  After the partion is formatted (side question: which option is correct to choose: NTFS or FAT?) and the files are copied, it claims it will shutdown and continue installation after restarting.  The computer boots up the normal way with OSX Leopard.  What am I missing? The only choices I'm really given are for partition size and File System.  Is there a way to continue setup using a hotkey as it boots? I figured that having the CD in the drive would be what would tell the computer to continue setup.  Help?

Comment: Closing as 'no longer relevant' to prevent migration and duplication on Super User. http://superuser.com/questions/40028/setting-up-windows-xp-with-bootcamp-why-does-osx-boot-and-skip-xp-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hold down the Alt button (between Ctrl and Cmd) when the Mac Gong sounds at bootup, and it should present you with OS choices. If not, use the latest version of BootCamp and use the same sequence.

Comment: Sorry but there's a better answer on superuser.